# How to I parse an SNS test notification from Lambda in python?

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have AWS Inspector setup to message an SNS topic when a scan has completed.  I also have a Lambda configured to trigger when a message is seen on that SNS topic.  The Lambda just reads in the message, calls out to the Inspector API to generate a URL of the scan report and then emails that URL to a mailbox.

All of that works quite nicely, except that when I use a **test** SNS message in the Lambda interface it errors.  I think the problem must be in the SNS message format because that's all that changing, but I don't really know how to get an actual full SNS to use as a test.

My test SNS looks like this:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "EventSource": "aws:sns",
      "EventVersion": "1.0",
      "EventSubscriptionArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:{{{accountId}}}:ExampleTopic",
      "Sns": {
        "Type": "Notification",
        "MessageId": "95df01b4-ee98-9cb9-9999-4c221d41eb5e",
        "TopicArn": "arn:aws:sns:eu-west-2:123456789012:ExampleTopic",
        "Subject": "example subject",
        "Message": {
          "template": "arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:accountID:target/0-0000aaaa/template/0-0000aaaa",
          "findingsCount": "{arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:account:rulespackage/0-0000aaaa}",
          "run": "arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:123456789012:target/0-0000aaaa/template/0-0000aaaa/run/0-0000aaaa",
          "time": "2021-01-29T12:29:24.758Z",
          "event": "ASSESSMENT_RUN_COMPLETED",
          "target": "arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:accountId:target/0000aaaa"
        },
        "Timestamp": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "SignatureVersion": "1",
        "Signature": "EXAMPLE",
        "SigningCertUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "UnsubscribeUrl": "EXAMPLE",
        "MessageAttributes": {
          "Test": {
            "Type": "String",
            "Value": "TestString"
          },
          "TestBinary": {
            "Type": "Binary",
            "Value": "TestBinary"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The part of my code that errors, including all the debug stuff I've done is:

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #get message from SNS
    #record = event['Records']
    #logger.debug(type(record))
    #logger.debug(record)
    
    message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    logger.debug(type(message))
    logger.debug(message)
    
    run_arn = message['run']
    logger.debug(type(run_arn))
    logger.debug(run_arn)
```

The error that comes up in the Lambda console is:

```
"errorMessage": "the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict",
```

That refers to the json.loads line.  But, as I mentioned, when I run an Inspector scan the Lambda works without errors (nothing but debug stuff in CloudWatch logs) and the email gets sent.  Where am I going wrong?!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your trying to parse a dict as a string that should be json.
`message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])`

the `Message` component is a dict and doesn't need to be parsed as json.

Just don't parse it as json:

```
message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
```

Comment: So my the test in the Lambda console now works fine, but when I run an Inspector scan and the Lambda is triggered it throws an error, "string indices must be integers" on line "run_arn = message['run']".

Comment: print the value of `message` and post it here

Comment: This is the value of message: 
`{
    "template": "arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:123456789123:target/0-ee11ee11/template/0-ee11ee11",
    "findingsCount": "{arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:123456789123:rulespackage/0-AizSYyNq=2}",
    "run": "arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:123456789123:target/0-ee11ee11/template/0-ee11ee11/run/0-1nkYs9qe",
    "time": "2021-02-24T09:46:15.296Z",
    "event": "ASSESSMENT_RUN_COMPLETED",
    "target": "arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:123456789123:target/0-ee11ee11"
}`

Comment: And yet this works: `message = {
  "template": "arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:516368158875:target/0-eqO1NPFu/template/0-A72WFYi0",
  "findingsCount": "{arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:146838936955:rulespackage/0-AizSYyNq=2}",
  "run": "arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:516368158875:target/0-eqO1NPFu/template/0-A72WFYi0/run/0-1nkYs9qe",
  "time": "2021-02-24T09:46:15.296Z",
  "event": "ASSESSMENT_RUN_COMPLETED",
  "target": "arn:aws:inspector:eu-west-2:516368158875:target/0-eqO1NPFu"
}
run_arn = message["run"]
print(run_arn)`